# Python 3 and sqlachemy model's properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, properties, sqlalchemy

I have two declarative sqlalchemy models.

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    ID = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    _Activities = relationship('Activities', lazy='subquery')

class UserCourseActivities(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'Activities'

     ActivityID = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
     UserID = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('Users.ID'))
     ActivityCount = Column(INTEGER)
```

Is there a way to have each instance of Users have a total (activity count) in their `__dict__`? I've tried adding other class attributes, but I fear I might have to use classical mappings. The Users table has a lot of relations that make the declarative method much more attractive. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Can I use the @column_property decorator? I have no idea how to actually use it though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that column property isn't a decorator.

```
activity_total = column_property(
    select(
        [func.sum(
            Activities.ActivityCount
        )
        ]).\
        where(Activities.UserID==PK1).\
        correlate_except(Activities)
) #This is officially the ugliest thing I have ever seen
```

This 'column' shows up in the User instances `__dict__` too.